# How does one review what flags one has raised?

Tags: support, flagging

I raised about 3 flags that I think should have been different flags. I started following the sequence of flag selection steps. I had a view/opinion that the questions should be either migrated or closed, but seemed to be forced down a path of choosing a close reason that seemed not quite what I felt was the case. (re: close - too old to migrate)

I think I perhaps should have flagged for moderator intention instead, as the issue is probably that I do not have the privilege of flagging for migration. Being concerned that I might get tag-banned... I'm wondering where to see what I have flagged, but can't find that capability.

How (if it is possible) does one review what flags one has raised?

Answer (score 3):

Go to your profile page (clicking your avatar / score in the top bar) and then choose the 'Activity' link at the top of your page.

[image]

There you will see the Impact panel, or the right. There is a link showing how many helpful flags you have raised, if you click that it'll take you to a dedicated page showing the flags you raised and how they were handled (or if they're still pending).

Not all flag types go direct to Moderators to action. Many of them just go to the general Review page so that the whole community can handle them (i.e. close flags don't go for moderators to action as they are rarely serious enough to need urgent attention).

Also, for reference, not even moderators can migrate posts deemed too old to migrate. All posts older than 60 days are not eligible for migration.

Don't be concerned about being banned as you'd have to *seriously* abuse the flagging system for anything like that to happen.